# How to make accordian tabs independent?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have this simple accordion and inside I have 3 accordion tabs. I want all accordian tabs to be open by default (I already got this working). My issue is that if I close **accordion Tab 1** and then I open it again it **closes all** the other accordion tabs. I want it so if I **close/open** any accordion tab it **shoudn't** affect at all the other tabs. Does anyone know how to make this happen. Thanks a lot in advance!

This is what I want:

[**Working example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-accordion?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

This is my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-pwyvc7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<p-accordion>
 <p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 1" [selected]="true">
   <ul>
     <li>Colors</li>
     <li>Cities</li>
     <li>Facility</li>
     <li>Hobbies</li>
   </ul>
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 2" [selected]="true">
    <ul>
      <li>Students</li>
    </ul>
</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 3" [selected]="true">
    <ul>
      <li>Music</li>
    </ul>
 </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[multiple]="true"` to your `p-accordion`

```
<p-accordion [multiple]="true">
 <p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 1" [selected]="true">
   <ul>
     <li>Colors</li>
     <li>Cities</li>
     <li>Facility</li>
     <li>Hobbies</li>
   </ul>
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 2" [selected]="true">
    <ul>
      <li>Students</li>
    </ul>
</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 3" [selected]="true">
    <ul>
      <li>Music</li>
    </ul>
 </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

more info on the [PrimeNG Docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion):